# How to calculate the number of frames extracted at certain FPS?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a bunch of videos in a folder at different fps. I need to calculate the number of frames that can be extracted at 0.5 fps.

Its kind of a simple mathematical problem, I need help on the formula.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "extract"? a video file has a fixed number of frames and a fixed duration. "frames per second" is a value implicit in the timestamp of each frame, although most videos have a single interval between all frames, hence a single constant FPS value.

Comment: I need to extract video frames from the video using ffmpeg. Each video will have different duration and different fps. lets say, I have a video of 1 minute at 25 fps. If i extract it at 1 fps i will get 25 frames. My question is, How many frames can be extracted at 0.5 fps?

Comment: "If i extract it at 1 fps i will get 25 frames" no you will not. how did you figure that?

Answer (score 0):

if the duration of video is t and I am assuming that's when the ffmpeg will terminate then it should ideally return you t/2 frames.

Comment: if the duration is 1:25 , at 0.5 and  at 0.1  how many frames can be extracted?

Comment: It's flour(fps * no of secs) . I am ignoring the keyframes. Here its 85 secs I guess so 42 and 8.